# how to push notification in flutter and web api

Tags: flutter, flutter-notification

I want the program to be able to send a request to the server every minute and return a list:
My List:
[{"NoteId": "Id", "Title": "Note Title", "Description": "Note Description", "AtDateTime": "1/7/2021 10:10:15"}]

Display an alarm with list record values if the value of the AtDateTime field is equal to the current time

I use a node js to connect the data.
Please Help Me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that performs a task in the background periodically.
But this only happens once every 15 minutes

for schedule task need to add package :[workmanager](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager)

for local notification add package:[flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications)

```
 dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
....
  # Use with the Workmanger for background jobs headless execution.
  workmanager: ^0.2.3
  # Use with FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin for local push notifications.
  flutter_local_notifications: ^1.4.4+2
```

add this code in :-> android -> app -> src -> main -> AndroidManifest.xml

```
<!-- Add below permission inside 'manifest' tag -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<!-- Add below permission inside 'application' tag -->
<receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

lib -> main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart'; 
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart'; 
import 'package:workmanager/workmanager.dart'; 

void main() { 
    
// needed if you intend to initialize in the `main` function 
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); 
Workmanager.initialize(         
    // The top level function, aka callbackDispatcher 
    callbackDispatcher,         
    // If enabled it will post a notification whenever 
    // the task is running. Handy for debugging tasks 
    isInDebugMode: true
); 
// Periodic task registration 
Workmanager.registerPeriodicTask( 
    "2",        
    //This is the value that will be 
    // returned in the callbackDispatcher 
    "simplePeriodicTask", 
    
    // When no frequency is provided 
    // the default 15 minutes is set. 
    // Minimum frequency is 15 min. 
    // Android will automatically change 
    // your frequency to 15 min 
    // if you have configured a lower frequency. 
    frequency: Duration(minutes: 15), 
); 
runApp(MyApp()); 
} 

void callbackDispatcher() { 
Workmanager.executeTask((task, inputData) { 
    
    // initialise the plugin of flutterlocalnotifications. 
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flip = new FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin(); 
    
    // app_icon needs to be a added as a drawable 
    // resource to the Android head project. 
    var android = new AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher'); 
    var IOS = new IOSInitializationSettings(); 
    
    // initialise settings for both Android and iOS device. 
    var settings = new InitializationSettings(android, IOS); 
    flip.initialize(settings); 
    _showNotificationWithDefaultSound(flip); 
    return Future.value(true); 
}); 
} 

Future _showNotificationWithDefaultSound(flip) async { 
    
// Show a notification after every 15 minute with the first 
// appearance happening a minute after invoking the method 
var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = new AndroidNotificationDetails( 
    'your channel id', 
    'your channel name', 
    'your channel description', 
    importance: Importance.Max, 
    priority: Priority.High 
); 
var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = new IOSNotificationDetails(); 
    
// initialise channel platform for both Android and iOS device. 
var platformChannelSpecifics = new NotificationDetails( 
    androidPlatformChannelSpecifics, 
    iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics 
); 
await flip.show(0, 'GeeksforGeeks', 
    'Your are one step away to connect with GeeksforGeeks', 
    platformChannelSpecifics, payload: 'Default_Sound'
); 
} 

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget { 
// This widget is the root of your application. 
@override 
Widget build(BuildContext context) { 
    return MaterialApp( 
    title: 'Geeks Demo', 
    theme: ThemeData( 
        
        // This is the theme 
        // of your application. 
        primarySwatch: Colors.green, 
    ), 
    home: HomePage(title: "GeeksforGeeks"), 
    ); 
} 
} 

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget { 
HomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key); 

final String title; 

@override 
_HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState(); 
} 

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> { 
@override 
Widget build(BuildContext context) { 
    return Scaffold( 
    appBar: AppBar( 
        title: Text(widget.title), 
    ), 
    body: new Container(), 
    ); 
} 
}
```

Comment: everything is similar and i also integration this notification my previous project. but not showing this time... its very bad time